# Derivative of Schur function

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, symmetric-polynomials

In his answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129854, R. Stanley says that the partial derivative (over the relevant x[i]) of the Schur function of a partition lambda of n equals the sum the Schur functions over the trimmed partions of lambda:

"Let $s_λ$ denote a Schur function and $p1=s1=x1+x2+\dots$. Then, $\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial p_1}=\sum_\mu s_\mu$, where the $μ$'s are obtained by removing a single box from $λ$."

If I work this out for $\lambda = \{3,1\}$, I find for the derivative 
$12 X[3]+ 108 X[2,1]+ 60 X[1,1,1]$ (substituting $X[i,j,k]$ for terms $x[1]^i*x[2]^j*x[3]^k$) while the trimmed partitions $\{2,1\}$ and $\{3\}$ produce 
$4 X[3]+ 24 X[2,1] + 12 X[1,1,1]$.

What am I missing? Can anyone provide an example of what is intended?

Comment: $\dfrac{\partial s_{\lambda}}{\partial p_1}$ means that you first write $s_{\lambda}$ as a polynomial **in the** $p_i$ (with no $x_i$'s, or $m_{\mu}$'s, or other things appearing), and then take the $p_1$-derivative.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: it surprises me that Chapter 7 of Enumerative Combinatorics, vol. 2. does not (seem to) mention derivatives of Schur functions (altough I'm a bad looker). Anyway, the expression "p_1 = s_1 = x_1 + x_2+.." does not seem to hint at a detour over the second Giambelli followed by a Newton-Girard. But maybe that was implied. Anon's mysteriously disapearing answer seem to head on that tack too.

Comment: anon's answer disappeared because it was wrong, as far as I recall.

Answer (score 6):

Stanley uses a cryptic description whose interpretation is easy for the initiated, but not for others. Remember that the ring of symmetric functions is equipped with an inner product for which the Schur functions form an orthonormal basis (you can take that as its definition, although there are also other descriptions). Now the operation written $\frac\partial{\partial p_1}$ is just the adjoint (in the sense of linear mappings) of the operation of multiplication by $p_1=s_1=\sum_i x_i$. Since that multiplication applied to $s_\lambda$ gives the sum of all $s_\mu$ where the diagram of$~\mu$ can be obtained by adding a square to that of$~\lambda$, its adjoint applied to $s_\lambda$ gives the sum of all $s_\mu$ where the diagram of$~\mu$ can be obtained by removing a square from that of$~\lambda$.

A way to view this operation as applied to any symmetric function $f$ is to single out one of the variables in which $f$ is  a symmetric function (since it is symmetric it doesn't matter which one), call that variable $y$ and the others $x_1,x_2,\ldots$; observing that $f$ is certainly symmetric in the $x_1,x_2,\ldots$, write it as a polynomial in $y$ with as coefficients symmetric functions in the $x_1,x_2,\ldots$, and then take the coefficient of the first power $y^1$ of$~y$  as outcome (we've used up one variable, but given the infinite supply this makes no difference; this is the Hilbert hotel in operation). In practice one doesn't need infinitely many variables: one can write $f$ as symmetric polynomial in variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ where $n$ is at least $\deg f$, and choose $y=x_n$ as "ultimus inter pares" which avoids renumbering (the degree conveniently drops by $1$, so $x_n$ is expendable).

If one takes the description of $s_\lambda(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ in terms of semistandard tableaux, one can partition the set of its terms according to the set of squares containing an entry$~n$ in the tableau. The parts of this partition of terms each define a product $s_\mu(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})x_n^d$, where $d$ is the number of squares in the fixed set containing an entry$~n$, and the diagram of $\mu$ consists of the remaining squares. It follows that the coefficient of $x_n^d$ is the sum of all such $s_\mu(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})$, where the diagram of$~\mu$ is obtained from that of$~\lambda$ by removing a horizontal strip of size$~d$. In particular, our operator maps $s_\lambda$ to the sum of all $s_\mu$ whose diagram is obtained from that of $\lambda$ by removing one corner.

To see that the operator coincides with formal differentiation with respect to $p_1$ when applied to a polynomial in $p_1,p_2,\ldots$, interpreted as power sum symmetric functions, one can either prove that it is a derviation which vanishes on $p_2,p_3,\ldots$ and sends $p_1\mapsto1$, or one can directly apply our description to a product $p_1^mf$ where $f$ is a factor on which the operator vanishes (a monomial in $p_2,p_3,\ldots$), using $p_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=p_1(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})+x_n$ and expansion of $(p_1(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})+x_n)^m$, giving as result of the operation $mp_1^{m-1}f$.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of Stanley's answer on MathOverflow is that:

- The schur functions are taken to be generating functions in infinitely many variables;
- In order to differentiate wrt $p_1$, one must first write $s_\lambda$ as a generating function in the power sum symmetric polynomials as $s_\lambda=f(p_1,p_2,\cdots)$.

Let's do a simpler example, say $\lambda=(2,1)$. The semistandard tableaux of shape $\lambda$ will come in a number of possible forms; we split them up into types for all naturals with $a<b<c$:

$$\color{blue}{
\begin{matrix} a & b \\ b\end{matrix} 
\qquad
\begin{matrix} a & a \\ b\end{matrix}} 
\qquad
\color{green}{
\begin{matrix} a & b \\ c\end{matrix}
\qquad
\begin{matrix} a & c \\ b\end{matrix}}$$

Thus, the schur function is $s_{(2,1)}=\color{blue}{m_{(2,1)}}+\color{green}{2m_{(1,1,1)}}$. Since $p_1^3=p_3+3m_{(2,1)}+6m_{(1,1,1)}$, we may write $s_{(2,1)}=(p_1^3-p_3)/3$, hence $\partial s_{(2,1)}/\partial p_1=p_1^2=p_2+2m_{(1,1)}$. Now the semistandard tableaux of shape $\color{purple}{(2)}$ and $\color{teal}{(1,1)}$ are all of the form (demarcated with a $|$)

$$\left. \color{purple}{\begin{matrix}a \\ b\end{matrix}} \quad \right| \quad \color{Teal}{\begin{matrix}a& b\end{matrix} \qquad \begin{matrix}a & a\end{matrix}} $$

Hence $\color{purple}{s_{(2)}=m_{(1,1)}}$ and $\color{teal}{s_{(1,1)}=m_{(1,1)}+p_2}$. Therefore

$$\frac{\partial s_{(2,1)}}{\partial p_1}=p_2+2m_{(1,1)}=s_{(1,1)}+s_{(2)},$$

exactly as claimed.

This should hold for schur functions of finitely many variables; simply apply the "evaluate $x_l=0$ for all $l>n$" ring homomorphism to the relations $s_\lambda = f(p_1,p_2,\cdots)$ and $\partial f/\partial p_1=\sum s_\mu$.

---

However, I am getting a missing or extraneous term in my own computation involving $s_{(3,1)}$. The three semistandard tableaux of shape $(3,1)$ are

$$\begin{matrix}1 & 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{matrix} \qquad \begin{matrix}1 & 2 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{matrix} \qquad \begin{matrix}1 & 3 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{matrix}$$

hence

$$s_{(3,1)}(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1^2x_2x_3+x_1x_2^2x_3+x_1x_2x_3^2=x_1x_2x_3(x_1+x_2+x_3).$$

Consulting the [NG formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities#Expressing_elementary_symmetric_polynomials_in_terms_of_power_sums) and the recursions they yield, this should be equal to

$$\frac{p_1^3-3p_1p_2+2p_3}{6}p_1$$

hence

$$\frac{\partial s_{(3,1)}}{\partial p_1}=\frac{4p_1^3-6p_1p_2+2p_3}{6}=x_1^2x_2+x_1x_2^2+x_1^2x_3+x_1x_3^2+x_2^2x_3+x_2x_3^2+4x_1x_2x_3.$$

The only semistandard tableau of shape $(3)$ is $\begin{matrix}1\\2\\3\end{matrix}$, hence $s_{(3)}(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1x_2x_3$.

The semistandard tableaux of shape $(2,1)$ they are

$$\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2\end{matrix} \qquad
\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ 3\end{matrix} \qquad
\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2\end{matrix} \qquad
\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3\end{matrix} \qquad
\begin{matrix} 1 & 3 \\ 2\end{matrix} \qquad
\begin{matrix} 1 & 3 \\ 3\end{matrix} \qquad
\begin{matrix} 2 & 2 \\ 3\end{matrix} \qquad
\begin{matrix} 2 & 3 \\ 3\end{matrix} $$

hence

$$s_{(2,1)}(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1^2x_2+x_1x_2^2+x_1^2x_3+x_1x_3^2+x_2^2x_3+x_2x_3^2+2x_1x_2x_3.$$

But this would indicate that $\partial s_{(3,1)}/\partial p_1=s_{(2,1)}+s_{(3)}\color{red}{+x_1x_2x_3}$, so I must have made a mistake somewhere. Perhaps someone else can see where my error is.

Comment: Your computation of $s_{(3,1)}$ in terms of the $p$'s seems wrong. Here's what Sage says (with ``p`` denoting the power-sum basis and ``s`` denoting the Schur basis): ``s([3,1]) == 1/8*p[1, 1, 1, 1] + 1/4*p[2, 1, 1] - 1/8*p[2, 2] - 1/4*p[4]``. Oh, I see where you went wrong: you forgot the semistandard tableaux with four distinct entries. (You can't "wlog" assume that you have only three variables.)

Comment: @darij: I am familiar with the power sums being $p_l=\sum x_i^l$. What does it mean when '`p`' has more than one index, e.g. `p[2,2]` - is that the same as the monomial sum $m_{(2,2)}$? If so, how is that a representation via power-sums, if it involves terms that are not pure power-sums?

Comment: Anyway, you say that we cannot wlog assume $s_{(3,1,0)}$ is a function of only three variables. [Definition 6 here](http://math.tntech.edu/techreports/TR_2009_2.pdf) suggests $s_\lambda$ can be a function of *any* number $n$ of variables (yielding the empty sum if $n<\lambda_1$). It occurs to me however that the claim in Stanley's answer doesn't specify how many variables there are - perhaps it only holds in full generality for infinitely many variables? Is this what you're getting at?

Comment: $p_{\left[x_1,x_2,...,x_k\right]}$ means $p_{x_1}p_{x_2}...p_{x_k}$ whenever $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_k$ are positive integers (just make sure not to apply this definition to cases where some $x_i$ are $0$, unless you artificially define $p_0$ to mean $1$).

Comment: I'm fairly sure that Stanley's $s_{\lambda}$ are Schur **functions**, not Schur **polynomials**. The difference is that functions are a-priori in infinitely many indeterminates (and are not polynomials, because they have infinitely many nonzero coefficients, though of course the symmetry determines all of them by finitely many ones). You can, of course, take a Schur function and turn it into a Schur polynomial by substituting $0$ for all but finitely many of its variables. But this does not commute with $\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}$, because the $\frac{\partial}{\partial p_j}$ ...

Comment: ... have different meanings for Schur functions and for Schur polynomials. (To compute $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial p_j}$ for a symmetric **function** $f$, you write $x$ as a polynomial in the infinitely many generators $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$, .... To compute $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial p_j}$ for a symmetric **polynomial** $f$ in $N$ variables, you write $x$ as a polynomial in the $N$ generators $p_1$, $p_2$, ..., $p_N$. These are different processes.)

Comment: That clears things up, thanks. I will expand on this in my answer later.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: thanks, I got it finally; the detour over the second Giambelli followed by a Newton-Girard was implied as it turns out. Checked it with a few big ones and it works.

Comment: @anon: thanks a bundle; climbing Mt. Stanley is quite hazardous, no?